# Center align 2 child div to parent div with flex box bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to center 2 child div to parent div, but they are appearing side by side at center.

**html**

```
<div class="container mt-5 box d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-notch text-danger"></i>
  <div class="">Content is being loaded</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

[image]

As we can loader and text are side by side, but I loader at center and very next line text, which also should be at center of parent.

e.g: loader should be just above the text **is being**

I am using bootstrap V5.0.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rshdpogj/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-column`

```
<div class="container mt-5 box d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-notch text-danger"></i>
      <div class="">Content is being loaded</div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tg02owcd/